# Help running what seems to be a directory in Terminal?

Tags: terminal, bash, skype

I'm trying to export my Skype chat history with this: https://github.com/Temptin/SkypeExport

After I'm in the downloads directory in Terminal, typing in (with my skype username substituted in)

```
./SkypeExport --db ~/Library/Application\ Support/Skype/your_username/main.db
```

results in

```
-bash: ./SkypeExport: No such file or directory
```

I thought this was because my main.db file wasn't in Home/Library/Applications etc, so I pasted in the path. Typing in

```
./SkypeExport --db ~/Users/myaccount/Library/Application Support/Skype/your_username/main.db
```

also results in no such file or directory

What am I doing wrong? Any responses are appreciated!

Answer (score 2):

The project has windows and os x binaries provided on the releases page so you can skip compiling it on your machine.

The error is clear above:

"bash: ./SkypeExport: No such file or directory"

Whatever folder you are in in Terminal  must contain the "SkypeExport" binary.

Try again by downloading the latest release (see the downloads list under the release you want):
https://github.com/Temptin/SkypeExport/releases

Unzip it in your Downloads folder, make sure the resulting "SkypeExport" file is directly in the Downloads folder, then type "cd ~/Downloads" in your terminal and follow the other steps.

This should work, since your error was that Terminal (bash) couldn't find SkypeExport in your current folder.

Answer (score 0):

The [README](https://github.com/Temptin/SkypeExport/blob/master/README.md) file for the project says [it's compiled code](https://github.com/Temptin/SkypeExport#compiling). Before you can run it you need to compile it.

For OS X it says:

> Mac OS X and Linux compilation is done using the included shell scripts.

I didn't see an shell scripts in the top level folder for the project but if you drill down to [this readme.txt](https://github.com/Temptin/SkypeExport/tree/master/src/SkypeExport) file it says:

> On Mac OS X and Linux, simply look in the _gccbuild folder and read the README for your platform, then issue the build script.

So we dig deeper and there is the [README for the macosx folder](https://github.com/Temptin/SkypeExport/blob/master/src/SkypeExport/_gccbuild/macosx/README.md). There are a handful of steps you should follow in there to compile the program. Once you're done with those you'll have a `SkypeExport` binary you can run that will do what you expect.

Comment: Ahh I completely missed that. In trying to run ./build_macosx.sh, I got this:

Building SkypeExport (Intel 32/64bit Universal Binary for Mac OS X)...
 - Using Build Cache: sqlite3.o
 - Building (New/Modified): skypeparser_core.o
In file included from ../../model/skypeparser_core.cpp:1:
../../model/skypeparser.h:16:10: fatal error: 'boost/filesystem.hpp' file not
      found
#include <boost/filesystem.hpp> // provides cross-platform path handling
         ^
1 error generated.
Compilation failed...

Comment: You need another set of libraries - at least Boost - look at the complete instructions for the project which include binaries

Comment: This was after I installed boost!